# Express: Disable headers for specific routes (Etag, set-cookie, etc)

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, http-caching

For my application, we have rest API and the webapp server from the same app. (it is small enought not to have separate deployment)

Is there any way I can exclude all `/api/*` route paths to disable caching and cookies?

Note: I cannot do `app.disable('etag')` as it will disable for the entire webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik this is currently not possible - also there are a few open issues on github like this one for example: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2472

As a workaround you could remove the headers for requests on the `/api`-route using something like this:

```
const onHeaders = require('on-headers')

// mount custom middleware for all api-requests
app.use("/api*", (req, res, next) => {
   removeHeaders(res);
   next();
});

function removeHeaders(res) {
  onHeaders(res, () => {
    res.removeHeader('ETag');
    // remove other headers ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Images/css/etc. from express.static still have Etag header...